Water Damage on Hardwood Floor by Front Door
I recently bought a house in Louisiana that has gorgeous hardwood floors. However, water gets in under the front door whenever it rains - you can see it pooling in really bad storms, and I assume moisture gets in other times as well. What can I do to protect the floor from water damage here?

Hardwood is vulnerable. Period. You protect the floor by preventing water intrusion. Your question should be about that, with necessary details about your entry and maybe photos. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

(This is precisely why modern vinyl floors are so popular.)

We need pictures and some idea of the conditions outside the front door that are causing the leaking. Is it a torrent or a trickle and where does it come from? If it's only a trickle or runoff down the front of the door, a higher threshold might solve it.

We would need pictures of the inside and outside of the door as well as details as to the surrounding area outside the door.  Then we may be able to give a worthwhile answer rather than wild guesses.

seal the door .....

Dig a drain out front.
That way the floor should stay dry after you have retreated it.

I think you know that this is an absurdly vague suggestion. Also, my hunch is that we're dealing with rainwater draining down the door, not puddling.

@isherwood with no detail provided by the OP about the exterior the suggestion of a drain is general... However, if the dwelling is at the bottom of a slope then that ay be difficult - again no detail from OP... If on a hill or close to the top then water should flow downhill - does for me...

Right. It's a faulty question that shouldn't be answered. This is standard on SE.

@SolarMike interesting, the water flows down the hill for you

@DIY75 and gravity is a myth, the earth sucks...
